# Generate Vector automatically with expression(X['i,n'])

Tags: r, vector, indexing, expression, rep

I'm trying to generate a vector of the length n that should look like this:

```
(expression(X['n,n'],.....,X['1,n']))
```

So for example:

```
n <- 3
```

I want to have:

(expression(X['3,3'],X['2,3'],X['1,3']))

I tried the following:

```
n <- 10
y<- c()


for (i in 1:n){
  y[i] <- rep(expression(X['i,n']),1)
}

y
```

Output:

```
expression(X["i,n"], X["i,n"], X["i,n"], X["i,n"], X["i,n"], 
    X["i,n"], X["i,n"], X["i,n"], X["i,n"], X["i,n"])
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use `bquote` to build the individual expressions and then i use `c` to combine them.

```
n<-5
do.call(c, 
    lapply(paste(n:1,n, sep=","), 
    function(x) 
        bquote(expression(X[.(x)]))
    )
 )
 # expression(X["5,5"], X["4,5"], X["3,5"], X["2,5"], X["1,5"])
```

Comment: Similarly, you could wrap the "list" to `as.expression` directly: `as.expression(lapply(paste(n:1, n, sep = ","), function(x) bquote(X[.(x)])))` because of the similar treatment of "list"s and "expression"s by R